# Photoshop Rectangle Marquee tool changing selection

Tags: adobe-photoshop, marquee-tool

I am trying to use my rectangle marquee tool to select some parts of my image to move them slightly. However, when I finish making my selection my selected area will change to a larger rectangle lower, higher, or on a 90-degree angle than what I want. I'm not sure if it is to do with something I'm doing or if I should simply restart photoshop. If anyone has any answers or tips they will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think you're going to need to show a video. Preferably with the whole application window.

Comment: I can't replicate this problem. Perhaps you have a faulty mouse?

Answer (score 1):

With the Marquee tool selected....

Be certain the `Style` dropdown at the top of the screen is set to **Normal**.

[image]